# using SELECT results as INSERT INTO VALUES shows CLR type error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to execute this SQL command in the VS Query Builder:

```
INSERT INTO DATA_TEMP (ITEM, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, TOTAL)
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATA_2.ITEM,
    (SELECT AMOUNT AS Expr1
     FROM DATA
     WHERE (QTR = 1) AND (DATA_2.ITEM = ITEM) AND (FY = @fy)
       AND (BU = @bu) AND (PERIOD = @per)) AS Q1,
    (SELECT AMOUNT AS Expr1
     FROM DATA AS DATA_3
     WHERE (QTR = 2) AND (DATA_2.ITEM = ITEM) AND (FY = @fy)
       AND (BU = @bu) AND (PERIOD = @per)) AS Q2,
    (SELECT AMOUNT AS Expr1
     FROM DATA AS DATA_3
     WHERE (QTR = 3) AND (DATA_2.ITEM = ITEM) AND (FY = @fy)
       AND (BU = @bu) AND (PERIOD = @per)) AS Q3,
    (SELECT AMOUNT AS Expr1
     FROM DATA AS DATA_3
     WHERE (QTR = 4) AND (DATA_2.ITEM = ITEM) AND (FY = @fy)
       AND (BU = @bu) AND (PERIOD = @per)) AS Q4,
    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS Expr1
     FROM DATA AS DATA_3
     WHERE (DATA_2.ITEM = ITEM) AND (FY = @fy) AND (BU = @bu)
       AND (PERIOD = @per)) AS Total
FROM DATA AS DATA_2 INNER JOIN
     DATA AS DATA_1 ON DATA_2.ID = DATA_1.ID
WHERE (DATA_2.ITEM = @item)
```

Gives me this error:

> Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Error Message: Parameter 3
>   ([C:\test.MDF].[].[unknown]): The CLR type does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions to access it.

Weird thing is, when I execute the SELECT and INSERT INTO commands individually, it works fine. It also works when I compile the website by the way.

But it doesn't work when using Stored Procedures which is why I wanted to know what's causing this.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the CLR or a Jet db fits into the problem here. Are any of the tables linked tables? Are any CLR types involved at all? You are positive this query is the problem and not some other line of code?

Comment: Can you post the schema of the `DATA` and `DATA_TEMP` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this query much simpler:

```
Insert DATA_TEMP( ITEM, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, TOTAL )
Select D2.ITEM
    , Min( Case When QTR = 1 Then D1.AMOUNT End ) As Q1
    , Min( Case When QTR = 2 Then D1.AMOUNT End ) As Q2
    , Min( Case When QTR = 3 Then D1.AMOUNT End ) As Q3
    , Min( Case When QTR = 4 Then D1.AMOUNT End ) As Q4
    , Sum( AMOUNT ) As Total
From DATA As D1
    Join DATA_2 As D2
        On D2.ID = D1.ID
Where ITEM = @item
    And FY = @fy
    And BU = @bu
    And PERIOD = @per
Group By D2.ITEM
```

Granted, this doesn't solve your CLR issue but it might make it simpler to test.

Comment: if only i knew that before i created all the sql commands for tihs project.

Comment: another question mate, since i see that you know quite a lot of sql, what if i wanted the items to be sorted in a specific way? can i do that in sql?

Comment: @Pod Mays - Do you mean beyond simply adding an Order By?

Comment: @Pod Mays - In case you did not know, another clause in the SQL language is the `Order By` specifically for sorting. It is generally the last clause (so it comes after the Group By).

Comment: What I need to do is order it specifically like this for example: A D C B G E F. What i'm doing now is making a temp table first and then calling the insert into commands manually just to maintain the order.

Comment: @Pod Mays - That's a different question but your answer is to use a Case expression in your Order By: `Order By Case ITEM When 'A' Then 1 When 'D' Then 2 When 'C' Then 3 When 'B' Then 4 When 'G' Then 5 When 'E' Then 6 When 'F' Then 7 End Asc`.

Comment: i'll try this tomorrow mate. you don't know how much this will help me if it worked. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely is due to a parsing problem.

Try adding the following to your final WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (DATA_2.ITEM = @item) AND (@fy = @fy) AND (@bu = @bu) AND (@per = @per)
```

I suspect it gets hung up on parameters within the SELECT portion of the code that are not defined in the final where clause.